# Execute a SQL Server stored procedure with dynamic parameters using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

We want to execute a stored procedure using EF.

Our approach is to provide input parameters dynamically as shown below :

```
PropertyInfo[] props = search.GetProperties();

foreach (var item in props)
{
     object itemValue = item.GetValue(SearchCondition, null);

     if (itemValue == null)
        parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter(string.Format("@{0}", item.Name), DBNull.Value));
     else
        parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter(string.Format("@{0}", item.Name), itemValue.ToString()));
}
```

and here are other common inputs:

```
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@order", (object)"desc"));
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@Page", page));
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@PageSize", rows));
```

and also output parameter:

```
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter()
{
    DbType = DbType.Int32,
    ParameterName = "@TotalCount out",
    SqlValue = DBNull.Value,
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
});
```

and here is execution code (running the stored procedure)

```
object[] para= parameterList.ToArray<object>();

var records = context.Database.SqlQuery<CustomerInformationReturnedList>(string.Format(@"Exec RTI.RptCustomerInformation {0}", parameters), para).ToList();
```

When we run it there is an exception that says:

> incorrect syntax near int

This is our executed stored procedure in SQL which runs correctly in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
EXEC    @return_value = [RTI].[RptCustomerInformation]
    @AccountNumber = NULL,
    @CardNumber = NULL,
    @CustomerNumber = NULL,
    @CustomerType = NULL,
    @NationalNumber = NULL,
    @Name = NULL,
    @FamilyName = NULL,
    @IdentityNumber = NULL,
    @IdSerial = NULL,
    @NationalityType = NULL,
    @InhabitancyType = NULL,
    @JobType = NULL,
    @c13 = NULL,
    @CustomerDefined = NULL,
    @OpenerBranch = NULL,
    @CodePosti = NULL,
    @RegisterNumber = NULL,
    @order = NULL,
    @Page = NULL,
    @PageSize = NULL,
    @TotalCount = @TotalCount OUTPUT

SELECT  @TotalCount as N'@TotalCount'
```

Comment: ParameterName = "@TotalCount out", this should only be ParameterName = "@TotalCount",