# Must declare the scalar variable "@Email"

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am trying to pass values from a database table to a couple of labels where the email column matches the email entered.I have passed the email entered from login page to this page using a session.Like This :

```
    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (AuthenticateUser(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtEmail.Text, chkBoxRememberMe.Checked);

        Session["Email"] = txtEmail.Text;
        Response.Redirect("~/Account.aspx");
     }
```

then i am passing the session value to lblEmail on ACOUNTS page.and then i am trying to retrieve values 'Name' and 'Balance' from database tabel where Emails match the one in the table.Like This:

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblEmail.Text = Session["Email"].ToString();
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABCD"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblRegister where @Email = " + lblEmail.Text, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        rdr.Read();
        lblName.Text = rdr["Name"].ToString();
        lblBalance.Text = rdr["Balance"].ToString();


    }
```

But i get a error message stating 'must declare the scalar vraiable @Email' on the line below:

```
   SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you do something like `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", lblEmail.Text);` before executing the query?

Comment: And I think you meant something like `where Email = @Email`, where "email" is DB field, and "@email" is parameter u pass in

Comment: Wait a second, I just realized you're building your query by concattenating strings. Don't! That's a huge security leak.

Comment: The problem is exactly what the error says.  You need to create the `@email` sql variable before you try to set it.

Comment: +1 for mentioning security

Comment: And if you're wandering why this is a big deal, Google "SQL injection". A malicious 12-year old could probably read or modify or delete your entire database with that.

Comment: Yes,i figured that out.Thanks.I shouldn't be doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this instead

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblRegister where Email = @Email", con);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", lblEmail.Text);
  SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  //...
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 1):

@Email indicates a variable, not a field name. If the field name in your table is @Email enclose it in square brackets... [@Email] but I would guess that the field name is Email.

Edit:

You also have an issue with the where statement, if you are sending text you need to enclose that in quotes:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblRegister where Email = '" + lblEmail.Text + "'", con);
```

This type of query, simply passing a value entered by the user will open you up to SQL injection.

[More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439182/execute-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-dynamic-parameters-using-entity-frame)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Email param in the wrong place.

Try using this instead:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblRegister where Email = @Email", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", lblEmail.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have already answered your initial problem regarding **@Email**.

### Here is what I found

Since you are using **FormsAuthentication**, you should not save **Email** in **Session state**. *(Normally, FormsAuthentication uses username, but email address is ok since you are retrieving user information by email address.)*

It defeats the purpose of using **FormsAuthentication**, because it already saves the **Email** in **FormsAuthenticationTicket**.

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (AuthenticateUser(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text))
   {
      // Thus all you need
      FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, true);
   }
}
```

### Global.asax.cs

You need this in order to retrieve the Email from cookie, and save the email in **IPrincipal Object**.

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    private void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie decryptedCookie =
            Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket =
            FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(decryptedCookie.Value);

        var identity = new GenericIdentity(ticket.Name);
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);

        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var email = User.Identity.Name;
}
```

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18108403/296861).