# VB Login form ASP.NET with membership or similar

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, forms, asp.net-membership

need some minor help with declaring a new array that could read the sql username of the user *(if logged in)* and store it for later use, either to use it for pages that only authorized users could see *(with simple if commands)* or lockdown the whole site with web.config authorization system that would allow roles only for admins.

***My code is this***

```
  Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        If Page.IsValid Then

            ' check for username & password in the database
            Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SoftCoD;User ID=sa;Password=fouf")

            ' Get the row corresponding the given username and password
            Dim strSQL As String = "Select * From users Where Name='" + txtUname.Text + "' and Password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "'"
            'I recommend not to use * in querys
            Dim dsc As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader
            dr = dsc.ExecuteReader()

            If dr.HasRows = True Then
                dr.Read()
                *g_sUser=Name????MsgBox(g_sUser)*

                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
            Else
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
            End If
            conn.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is nothing to do with ASP.Net Membership. Instead, you can use [FormAuthentcation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22918953/296861) for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following method for holding the username for future use

- [Session](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp)
- [QueryString](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_querystring.asp)

Method 1 : Session

```
 dr = dsc.ExecuteReader()
 If dr.HasRows = True Then
   dr.Read()
   session("user")= g_sUser
   Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
 Else
   Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
 End If
```

Method 2 : QueryString

```
 dr = dsc.ExecuteReader()
 If dr.HasRows = True Then
   dr.Read()
   Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?username=g_sUser")
 Else
   Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
 End If
```